# How can I change the default directory when open project in R?

Tags: r, filesystems

I am beginning to use projects in R.

I have set the default working directory in Global Options to

X:/Users/example/R

However when I open R and click open projects I will look in the standard windows folder "this PC/Documents".

Strange because my RProfile.site has correctly set my working dir to "X:/Users/example/R"

When opening R it seems to work since getwd() returns as it should X:/Users/example/R and works fine as long as I not click open projects.

What am I doing wrong and how could I set the default directory to X:/Users/example/R when I pclick open projects?

Here is my .RProfile.site

```
# set the default help type
  options(help_type="html")

main.dir <- 'X:/Users/example/R'
setwd(main.dir)
options(max.print=2000)
# set a CRAN mirror
local({
  r <- getOption("repos")
  r["CRAN"] <- "https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/"
  options(repos = r)
})
```

Jorgen

Comment: Do you have an X drive?

Comment: Since getwd() returns 'X:/Users/example/R' - yes